# Derivation of $[x + y] = [x] + [y + x - [x]]$ and the range of the $floor$ $function$

Tags: functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

One of the properties of the *floor function* is this : $[x + y] = [x] + [y + x - [x]]$

Please let me know what the derivation of this property is...

Another question that I have is : What is the range of the *floor function*? Is it $\Bbb Z$, the set of all integers? Please let me know

And, I also have a little 'less mathematical question' : Is the derivation of properties of *functions*, like this one important to be known and there are about 10 properties of the *floor function* given in my textbook, do I have to learn each one of those? I mean will those properties be used in further concepts or are those just a one time thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know $[x+n]=[x]+n$ for all n $\in Z$

So you RHS=$ [x]+[y+x-[x]]=[x]+[y+x]-[x]=[y+x]=LHS$ as [x] $\in Z$

Comment: Thanks, and what about the range of the $floor$ $function$ and the other $non-mathematical$ question?

Comment: Well, if domain is R then range is Z. Also, there are properties of [x] which you will study now but will use it in calculus later.  Say x-1<[x] $\le x$ is extensively used in limits. So, better to know and n understand all the properties. And in my opinion derivations help to understand the results better.

Comment: Thank You, it was really helpful )

Comment: You are welcome. Actually i have done a series on greatest integer function. It might be of some help to you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OmisxHeYeOY&list=PLoetsRqdeRZngtIS3jdS6M_2OdTcpOwgA

Comment: Thanks again...!

Comment: In "real life", you make a list of the properties of floor functions and save them on your computer **where you can get at them easily**. In time, you will remember the ones you use (need) the most.